# Outlining text in InDesign CS4

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I'm producing a large paged brochure in InDesign CS4, I was wondering if there is a way to outline all the fonts used when exporting the file as a PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an external script: *CreateOutlinesRemoveOriginal_all.jsx*

to download [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D8HXDqHmo-GGdQ9dWy9X7Ifbp9BUmUej/view)

```
myPage = app.activeWindow.activePage;
for (j=myPage.textFrames.length- 1; j >= 0; j--){
try{
    myPage.textFrames[j].createOutlines();
    myPage.textFrames[j].remove();
    }catch(e){}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Danielillo, that works great and will save me a lot of time! Cheers, Tom.

Comment: Is this still working for last versions of indesign?